# Configure view to display a list of nodes with identical term id/name

Tags: views, flags

How could I configure the view to display a list of nodes that with the identical term id/name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a filter to display nodes that has term with name/id = X. This is done through the interface by clicking add filter and selecting either term name or term id.